# How do I implement a python function that can gives the position of seris of zeros in a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need to find positions of all series of zeroes in my string, and I am having really hard time implementing a python function that can do it.

It's output needs to be something like:

**For Input:** 100010001

**Output:** `[(7,5), (3,1)]`

Because there are series of zeroes at index 7 to 5 and 3 to 1 of the input string.

**For Input:** 11000010101

**Output:** `[(8,5)]`

Zeroes at position 1 and 3 are ignored because they are alone (not in a series)

Comment: Please be aware that open ended requests for code or advice are generally off-topic as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Take a moment to revisit the [ask] and related help pages; you can [edit] your question to *provide details or clarity* on what specific task you are struggling with or add *debugging details* such as a [mre] for what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The question here, as far as I can tell describes the problem clearly and is not open ended. The issue with previous version of the answer has been resolved. My problem has been solved & I think opening it for everyone now might help others with similar problem in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this, we keep on incrementing `i`, once we see a `0`, we start looking for all `0`s starting from that `0`. And add them to the list if number of continuous zeroes is more than 1 -

```
def get_zeroes(s):
    zeroes = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        digit = s[i]
        i += 1
        if digit != '0':
            continue
        start = i - 1
        while i < len(s) and s[i] == '0':
            i += 1
        if i - start > 1:
            zeroes.append((len(s) - start - 1, len(s) - i))
    return zeroes
```

```
>>> get_zeroes('100010001')
[(7, 5), (3, 1)]
>>> get_zeroes('11000010101')
[(8, 5)]
>>> get_zeroes('10001000')
[(6, 4), (2, 0)]
>>> get_zeroes('00001000')
[(7, 4), (2, 0)]
```

Comment: This fails for trailing zeroes, e.g. ``get_zeroes('10001000')``.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @MisterMiyagi, fixed it and added a test case for it.

Comment: It's still not working for trailing zeroes.

Comment: @SpiralWire did you use the updated function? Please check the output for `00001000` above. Do you have an example for which its not working?

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's working now. I wasn't being shown the updated function before. It only showed after I opened the page in a new tab.